# Copy and paste information into another workbook based on desired condition in the other workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i have 2 workbook one is called the "Active master project" that content more than 1 country new projects and its information. While the other workbook called "easy project tracker", there is an empty sheet that will copy and paste the new projects information based on "Singapore" country only. I managed to come out with a code but it only copy one row of its information from "Singapore" country to the easy project tracker workbook. However, in the "Active master project" it consist of more than one "Singapore" country in the "Country" column. In addition, the codes below keep replacing the rows of the column headers when i tried to run it instead of pasting the projects information into an empty row of the easy project tracker workbook.
This is the code that i have so far:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long '<~~ Not Integer. Might give you error in higher versions of excel
    Dim strSearch As String

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("U:\Active Master Project .xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("New Upcoming Projects")

    strSearch = "Singapore"
    With ws1

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> I am assuming that the names are in Col A
        '~~> if not then change A below to whatever column letter
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        With .Range("A4:A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '~~> Destination File
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("New Upcoming Projects")
     With ws2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A4"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

       copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With
End Sub
```

I would need a code that would allow me to run through all the rows of the active master project workbook and copy all the information and paste it into easy project tracker workbook which consist of "Singapore" in the Country column, which is column A. The code will stop running when there is no more rows found in the active master workbook. I hope anyone could assist me. Thank you.